# Thymeleaf downloads login blank file instead navigate to login.html (Springboot)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Can't navigate from `index.html` to any other page, when clicking the button to navigate a blank login file is downloaded. I think this problem is linked to security file because at the beginning I didn't had it but after adding it many things have been broken.

This is the html code :

```
<a href="login" th:href="@{/login}" id = "LOGIN" class="active">Log In</a>
```

And this is security file :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    // https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/register","/login","/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}
```

There is a `login.html` file in templates.

Comment: Please consider putting the implementation of function annotated with `@GetMapping("/login")` in your controller.

Comment: @RatulSharker login shouldn't be mapped, spring already provides its own controller that do this. This is what I knew

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you override the default login page by specifying `.loginPage(some_string)`, then the Spring Security default login configuration will be deactivated.

It does not matter what the value of `some_string` is, it is considered a custom login page even if the value is `"/login"`.

In other words, with your current configuration, when you are overriding the default login page, Spring Security expects you to create the mapping for your custom login endpoint.

As Ratul Sharker said in the comment above, you need to add a `@GetMapping("/login")` that returns your custom login page.

Comment: So should I add a controller to login? I thought it should be delegated to spring boot

Comment: Yes, you need to add a controller for the login page, because you are overriding the default login page.